# Unchase OpenAPI (Swagger) Connected Service : requested params are set as Dictionary<string, string> insted of IDictionary<string, object>

Tags: c#, wcf, openapi, webapi

while working my generated out put is making request object as WepApi object parameter generating as Dictionary<string, string>
as below

var dictionary_ = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string>>(json_, _settings.Value);

what i think my solution is IDictionary<string, object>
can anyone help on it?

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be related to an [NSwag bug](https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag/issues/3414) that was introduced in `NSwag.ApiDescription.Client` version `13.10.9` - the client will always try to URL encode the request if the endpoint can consume `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Downgrading the NSwag version to `13.10.8` fixed the issue for us.